# Selecting elements of a cell using a logical matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

Imagine I've a empty cell array like this:

```
dim = [100,200];

x = cell(dim);
```

And I want to replace the diagonal elements of `x` with `'a'` (string). This is what I've done:

```
mask = logical(eye(dim));
x{mask} = {'a'};
```

However, I recieve the following error:

> The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy
>   the left hand side
>
> Error in test (line 28)
>
> x{mask} = {'a'};

I also tried:

```
mask_2 = find(mask == true);
x{mask_2} = {'a'};
```

But I get the same error. Is there any way to solve this? I want the script to be as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways that I know to do this.

The first is to use addressing with parentheses instead brackets. This returns a cell array reference for each address, so you have to assign a cell array to the result:

```
x(mask) = {'a'};
```

The second is to use bracket addressing, which will return a comma-separated list. What's that? You've never heard of a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) in Matlab? That's because it's Matlab's least-understood data type, even though I assure you that you've seen it before. Read the link for more information. I found that a lot of Matlab's "weirdness" made more sense once I understood what a comma-separated list was and where they are used.

Anyway, if you tried to write `x{mask} = 'a'`, it wouldn't work, because you are trying to assign a single value to a comma-separated list of references. You can use the `deal` function to assign to each reference by using some cleverness to concatenate the references:

```
[x{mask}] = deal('a');
```

And there you have it. Two ways to assign to your cell array using logical indices. I'm not sure which is faster though, you'll have to test that out yourself.

Comment: Very nice answer. I don't think that a comma-separated list can be strictly considered a data type. But you are absolutely right that _a lot of Matlab's "weirdness" makes more sense once you understand what a comma-separated list is and where they are used_

Answer (score 4):

To refer to a set of cells, use what the Matlab documentation calls "smooth parentheses", or what we call just normal parentheses:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html

```
x(mask) = {'a'}
```

results for `dim = [5,6]`:

```
x =
{
  [1,1] = a
  [2,1] = [](0x0)
  [3,1] = [](0x0)
  [4,1] = [](0x0)
  [5,1] = [](0x0)
  [1,2] = [](0x0)
  [2,2] = a
  [3,2] = [](0x0)
  [4,2] = [](0x0)
  [5,2] = [](0x0)
  [1,3] = [](0x0)
  [2,3] = [](0x0)
  [3,3] = a
  [4,3] = [](0x0)
  [5,3] = [](0x0)
  [1,4] = [](0x0)
  [2,4] = [](0x0)
  [3,4] = [](0x0)
  [4,4] = a
  [5,4] = [](0x0)
  [1,5] = [](0x0)
  [2,5] = [](0x0)
  [3,5] = [](0x0)
  [4,5] = [](0x0)
  [5,5] = a
  [1,6] = [](0x0)
  [2,6] = [](0x0)
  [3,6] = [](0x0)
  [4,6] = [](0x0)
  [5,6] = [](0x0)
}
```

Comment: I've created a MATLAB chat room for us to discuss things MATLAB related, or for discussions that span beyond the limitations of a single comment.  Visit us when you have time! - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the explanations given here, you can also avoid creating the (potentially large) logical array, if that is its only purpose, and use [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) to assign the values directly using the [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function:

```
dim = [100,200];
x = cell(dim);
x(sub2ind(dim,1:dim(1),1:dim(1))) = {'a'};
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, the `sub2ind` function is easy to side-step here since the stride between diagonal elements is a constant value (the row count).  So the above can be simplified to

```
x(1:dim(1)+1:dim(1)^2) = {'a'};
```

Comment: Or, `x(1:dim(1)+1:dim(1)*dim(2)) = {'a'}`

Comment: In this case it's very easy to sidestep `sub2ind`: `x(1:size(x)+1:end) = {'a'}`

Comment: @beaker Well said :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo I like yours better. ;-)

Comment: @beaker That function is indeed not necessary here. I guess I'm biased since I use it all the time to update unsymmetric matrices. ^^"

Answer (score 1):

another option  (one liner, my favorite solutions), using the logic that was presented in the question (`eye` function etc):

```
x=num2cell(char(eye(n,m)*97),n)
```

where `dim=[n,m]`, and `97` will encode for the string `'a'`...